# Make record triggered flow run after the record is updated or created

Tags: visual-workflow

please tell me how to create record triggered flow that runs after the record is saved not before? When I create a new flow I dont have this option. So from where can I configure this?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Please take a look at the section just below "Set Entry Conditions" one. There  you'll see "**Optimize the Flow for:**" and the default option is the one you're looking for: "Actions and Related Records".
Its description states:

> Update any record and perform actions, like send an email. This more flexible flow **runs after the record is saved to the database**

[image: triggered flow option]

Keep in mind that it runs after the record is saved, but before the commit to the database. Please refer to [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).

The trail [Build Flows with Flow Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/build-flows-with-flow-builder) is a good way to take confidence with flow.